# How do I avoid persisting data through ViewState for a child control in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, onload, onpreinit

I have a control (say, a DataGrid or a ComboBox) which is a child of a user control.  I want to DataBind it on every request, rather than have it's state persist through ViewState.  I need to leave `EnableViewState=true` however.  This means, I think, that I need to call DataBind before TrackViewState() is called.

I read the fantastic blog post [TRULY Understanding ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/truly-understanding-viewstate.aspx) and it answers my question in `4. Initializing child controls programmatically`.  However, the article's solutions are less-than-ideal: create child controls dynamically (I'm not and can't -- too much existing code), use a 3rd party CodeExpressionBuilder (would much prefer this was in code-behind), and use OnPreInit (which "doesn't help you what-so-ever if you are developing a CONTROL").

Since that article is rather old (circa 2006) I was hoping that newer versions of ASP.NET rectify the situation such that there are better solutions now.  So, community, are there any GOOD ways to do this?

Comment: Custom control doesn't support .aspx file like user control, so you have to add child controls programmatically. Are you sure you're talking about custom control here?

Comment: Yes, unless my semantics are confused. Is a custom control different than a user control?  I have an .aspx that uses an .ascx.  The .ascx declaratively uses a Data Grid and a Combo Box, and I want to DataBind them without persisting the data in ViewState.

Comment: Yes, Custom control and User Control are different. ASCX file means that you have User Control.

Why do you need to keep EnableViewState=true? You just need to set it to false and in Page.Load add lines to initialize DataSource and do DataBind.

Comment: @vitaly - I think you're referring to the difference between "server" controls and user controls?  Server controls do not support the .ascx markup file while user controls do.

Comment: @Vitaly: Thanks, I corrected the main post, though I'm not sure I understand the difference exactly.  I tried to look it up and [this promising post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667) begins by saying, "User controls are custom, reusable controls..." :)

Comment: @Eric - Microsoft calls them custom controls, but server controls might be just another term for the same thing.

@Scott - here custom means that they're defined by you, customized by you. Major difference between custom and user controls is that custom doesn't have design file, and all the layout is set up in the back-end code. That's why you should add child controls programmatically. But you can use custom controls from different ASP.NET apps. While user controls can be used only from app where user control is defined.

Comment: @Eric, here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx) Microsoft calls it "custom server controls" :) I think we can agree on that.

Comment: @All: Awesome... now if only someone actually had an answer for the question! :)

Comment: @Scott - how come you can't just explicity databind the child datagrid or combo box control?  Is there some reason you don't have access to the object that is the parent control's datasource property?  You should just be able to databind the child control in the parent control's Page_Load method?  If you cannot, what is the reason?

Comment: @Eric: I can (and do) databind it.  The problem is, if I do it anywhere convenient, it will end up in the ViewState and my ViewState will bloat unnecessarily.

Comment: @Scott, as I was saying why don't you just set control's EnableViewState to False and in PageLoad do manual binding? ViewState is required for PostBack (to compare old and new data) and if you don't need this, just set control.EnableViewState = False

Comment: @Vitaly: I do need ViewState for other properties of the control, just not the databound information.  If you databind in PreInit it won't be stored in the ViewState (see that article i referenced in the question) but for various reasons (see my question) that's annoying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Scott,

I think there's a misunderstanding of how ASP.NET Web Forms framework works. So just a little theory first.

ASP.NET Web Forms pages have design and code-behind files. Design file has HTML markup and "controls" which are reference tags to either user or custom controls. Every element that has attribute `runat = "server"` is server control (meaning it is accessible from the code behind by its ID).

When page is opened in the browser, ASP.NET takes design file and processes these control references and finally generates pure HTML.

ViewState is a hidden variable in HTML that keeps internal state of all controls that are marked with `runat = "server"` and also have property EnableViewState set to True.

Say you have DataGrid with `EnableViewState = False`. This grid has rows that contain server controls and you want them to be in ViewState. You still can have them have `EnableViewState = True` and be in ViewState and you still can bind to events for these sub-controls.

So even though DataGrid is not in ViewState, its children can be in ViewState and you can handle appropriate events.

You will need to initialize DataGrid in the PageLoad event every time if you want it to show data after every postback.

ViewState keeps internal state of control, so you can't have some properties of control in ViewState and others not in ViewState. But you can have child controls (they're not properties, they're subentities!) to be in ViewState even though parent control is not in ViewState.

Let me know if you want me to be more specific on this. If you want to go deep inside there's a brilliant book from Nikhil Kothari about developing controls. I think I saw it somewhere as e-book.

Comment: Thank you for a good summary of ViewState, but I don't believe that it answers my question.  Read the article I referenced, if you haven't already, especially the section I mentioned, and I think you'll see what i mean.

Comment: Scott, could you tell what questions do you still have after my explanation?